# iMacros TAG POS with XPATH

Tags: imacros

Normal way of clicking link:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Contact<SP>me
```

Instead, I want to use XPATH for more accuracy, my try:

```
TAG XPATH="(/html/body//a[contains(@href,"contact") or contains(@href,"about")])[1]"
```

But this is not the correct way, I am getting syntax error (-910)

I don't know if it's possible to navigate with XPATH like this, but [here](http://wiki.imacros.net/V7_Relative_positioning) it says *Alternatively, you can use XPATH to position the tag* so I guess I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question self-solved after changing `"contact"` and `"about`" to `'contact'` and `'about'`

```
TAG XPATH="(/html/body//a[contains(@href,'contact') or contains(@href,'about')])[1]"
```

Comment: Great. XPATH is rarely used but it can be really helpful . Thanks for sharing.